# How to enable the use of HTML tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

when I list out information from my database through C#, if the info contains html tags such a; pagagraph (p) or title (h1) it does not use them but simply list them out as is, I searched the internet and have not found a solution to my problem yet. What I've discovered is that people have had problems with saving their info onto the server that uses html tags but my problem lies in the fact that when the info is listed out the tags just stay text.

Comment: aspx, as in I write the code for this website on controllers which are .cs as well as on .cshtml pages.

Comment: You're looking for `Html.Raw()`.  Beware that this is a security hole; learn about XSS attacks.

Comment: In MVC you can use the @Html.Raw extension method.

Comment: How would I use that? and is there a way of putting it only to be used on certain pages for security reasons.

Comment: @MW just call @Html.Raw({your text}) and you are done. Just make sure you trust whats in it cuz its XSS injectable

Comment: What framework is this? ASP.NET MVC? Web Forms? Something else?

Comment: yes of course, I would never ever thinking of using it somewhere where there is even the slightest possibility of malicious code being injected.

Comment: @mason It's ASP.NET MVC on Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

If you have HTML tags in a database that you want to appear on in a browser as text, you can convert them with HtmlEncode() so that `<div>` will be displayed on the screen instead of interpreted as the beginning of and HTML div.

If your prblem is the other way, where it's stored in your database as `&lt;div&gt;` and you want an actual div, you can use HtmlDecode.()